How does rolling update work for a statefulset in kubernetes
I am trying to do a rolling update of my stateful set by setting the updateStrategy in the STS spec but it looks like on deleting the statefulset pod, it gets terminated and a new pod is coming up. So, question is I want to keep my existing pod running on deletion command from client and once the new pod is up and running my old one should be terminated.  How can I achieve this with statefulset? Is it possible with statefulset like we do rolling updates in a deployment resource?

It is not possible to update statefulset like rolling updates in a deployments, as mentioned in the doc:

When a StatefulSet's .spec.updateStrategy.type is set to RollingUpdate, the StatefulSet controller will delete and recreate each Pod in the StatefulSet. It will proceed in the same order as Pod termination (from the largest ordinal to the smallest), updating each Pod one at a time.

So you can use bluegreen deployment or use the OnDelete update strategy. This allows you to manually delete pods to trigger the StatefulSet controller to create new pods with the updated template.
Here is the blog by Ajay explaining about it in a detailed version.

Thanks, but if it is not possible to update in rolling fashion then wondering why do we have a rollingupdate strategy in the statefulset spec?

rollingupdate strategy in the statefulset spec will ensure to have minimal downtime where in deployment it can be reduced to zero

When you create a StatefulSet set with 3 replicas, Kubernetes will create pods with names set-0, set-1, and set-2. These will always be the names of those pods, and there can only be one pod at a time with a given name. So there's no way in this model that a StatefulSet could roll out a new instance of (say) set-2 without deleting the old set-2 first.
Instead, the StatefulSet rolling update strategy deletes pods and recreates them under the same name. It's the same mechanism done by the older "on delete" strategy, just done automatically for you instead of manually.
